# Creating a data pair (not a dictionary, but two seperate data) in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

I have an application with the following HTML table (dynamically added using the following code:

```
function generateTableRow() {
var emptyColumn = document.createElement('tr');

emptyColumn.className ='data';



emptyColumn.innerHTML = '<td><a class="cut">-</a><span class="itemcode" contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td colspan="2"><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable>100.00</span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span class="itemquantity" contenteditable></span></td>'+
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>'+
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' ;


return emptyColumn;
}
```

Now there is a save button, which on click does the following:

```
$( ".save" ).on("click", function(){
alert("Clicked");

$("tr.data").each(function() {

    var code = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1) span').html();
    var quantity = $(this).find('td:nth-child(4) span').html();        

 });

});
```

I need the same to send AJAX with json data to server.

My doubt is how to create a json object, with a code and quantity pair.

Here code is the product code and quantity is the product quantity. So, if there are four rows dynamically generated, there would be four codes and quantity pair. How to create a pair like that to be sent as json data to back-end (I am using Django, although that is not relevant).

Hence my JSON should look like:

```
[{"itemcode":"code1","itemquantity":"quantity1"},{"itemcode":"code2","itemquantity":"quantity2"},...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object and send it to server as a model...

first, you should create a list before each loop

```
var items = [];
```

and in each loop you should define object, fill it and then push on items

```
var item = {
 item.Code : $(this).find('td:nth-child(1) span').html(),
 itemQuantity : $(this).find('td:nth-child(4) span').html()        
};
items.push(item);
```